# Get coordinates of object following curve using follow path constraint

Tags: objects, constraints, coordinates

I have an empty and a curve with locations both set at the origin (0,0,0) of my scene. The empty precisely follows the curve using a "follow path" constraint with the curve having "Path Animation" checked and key frames set on the timeline. I would like to know the coordinates (global) of the empty as its position is modified by the curve along the timeline. As I scrub the timeline and visually watch the empty follow the curve path, I can't find anything in the properties panels to indicate the transformed coordinates of the empty, its location always reads (0,0,0). How would I find this info to use say in a driver?

Comment: When you chose the objects transform channel for the driver there are 3 options available. `Local Space`, `Transform Space` and `World Space`. The latter takes the effect of constraints into account.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed! I wish there was a display option to view "modified" coordinates in the properties panel so you didn't have to get in to driver expressions to view this info.